# The Theoretical Minimum: Classical Mechanics Lecture 3 Exercise 4 (Simple harmonic oscillator)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

This is the exercise that my question entails:

http://www.madscitech.org/tm/slns/l3e4.pdf

Why is the derivative of $A \cos(\omega)$ not 0, because isn't $\omega$ just a constant?

It was defined in the text as:

$$k/m = \omega^2$$

Where $k$ and $m$ are from the equation for a simple harmonic oscillator:

$$F = -kx$$

I'm pretty sure he just swapped out $x$ and $m$, but it's still confusing. Nevertheless, shouldn't the $d [A\cos(\omega)]/dt$ still be $0$?

Comment: It is $A\cos(\omega t)$ not $A\cos(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just $\omega$.

The cosine function need an adimensional argument, and $\omega$ is an angular velocity, hence it's measured in rad/second.

The correct factor is $\omega t$, in order to lead to radians.

Probably there is a misprint.

Comment: Nope, just my eyes playing tricks on me, haha. Thanks.